# Will gcloud using my SSH key to login or I will always need to login via the web?

Tags: gcloud

I am trying to perform a very basic command like:

```
gcloud compute machine-types list
```

And I get this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.machine-types.list) There was a problem
>   refreshing your current auth tokens: invalid_grant: Bad Request Please
>   run:

It tells me to login using 'gcloud auth login' which opens up the browser.

Is it possible to use a ssh key to skip this authentication process or I have to do this always?  ssh keys are for accessing compute instances only?

Just trying to understand what SSH keys are used for and how this web based authorization fits into the picture here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you authenticate to `gcloud` (and GCP services) using credentials from a Google (often Gmail) account. Such accounts use 3-legged (O)Auth and this requires the browser prompt for the human to confirm the scopes etc.

If you haven't, you should confirm the prompt, copy the token provided and paste that back into gcloud so that auth will occur transparently.

This process is different than SSH'ing to Compute Engine instances.

When you run `gcloud compute machine-types list`, you're authenticating (and being authorized) by Google Cloud Platform to invoke (meta)services.

When you run `gcloud compute ssh ...`, the command uses ssh to connect you to the (Linux) instance.

> **NOTE** `gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser` is available too ([link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login)). This requires you to separately launch a browser and complete the process but it doesn't launch the browser directly from the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to automate some sort of service, that runs cloud commands on-demand, without operator/browser involved - your best bet would be to create a Service Account for that task, get the key for that account and activate it, using

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=my-service-account-key-file.json
```

If this service runs on Google Cloud platform - you don't even need to deal with the key. Just associate the service account with an instance you are running.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances